# Permission issues with Craft 3 CMS and local asset uploads

Tags: permissions, composer-php, craftcms, scotchbox

I have been going through the steps of configuring Craft 3 CMS locally. I used Scotchbox and Composer for the installation on Ubuntu via MacOS Mojave, and up until the point of uploading an asset to the local server, everything has been fine... Now I constantly receive the message:

> *Upload failed. The error message was: “Impossible to create the root directory "/Users/marcus/projects/craft-two/web/images/drinks". mkdir(): Permission denied*

I have since tried to update permissions, making the project folder `craft-two` be readable, writable and executable for users and groups, but this hasn't helped.

Would greatly appreciate some guidance... Have searched a fair bit to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You've configured the asset volume incorrectly.  It's really easy to do.
On the file system path. Don't lead with a "/"

If you put "/images/backgrounds", then change it to "images/backgrounds"

The default placeholder in Craft for this configurable field can make this an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://yourlocal.test/admin/utilities/php-info and check which is the username/group that your web server is running. After that you can set your correct user permissions with this command:

```
sudo chown -R username.group /Users/marcus/projects/craft-two
```

also be sure that `/Users/marcus/projects/craft-two/web/images/drinks` is read/write

```
sudo chmod 775 -R /Users/marcus/projects/craft-two/web/images
```